# How to execute python script from php using shell with passing form parameter on ubuntu

Tags: php, python

I have create this index.php page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>            
        <h2>The select Element</h2>            
        <form method="post">
            Name:<br>
            <select name="name">
            <option value="Archana">Archana</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>        
    </body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $name=$_POST['name'];
     echo "Name: ". $name . "<br />";
     echo "Results from CCTV";
     echo "</br>";
     $output = shell_exec("python3 index.py $name");
     echo $output;

}
?>
```

And this is my python script `index.py`
    import sys
    print(sys.argv[1])

I have to run this in `ubuntu`.

Once I submit form its redirect o python script. 
And get response from python script, but its only show output for few seconds.
I want to python output from php as normal output.

Comment: _"its only show output for few seconds"_ - Are you doing some redirect or something? There's no reason for things you echo to disappear. Btw, you should probably put the output inside the `body` of your document.

Comment: Another thing, your script is _highly_ insecure. Anyone can post what ever commands they want (within the user that runs PHP's permissions of course). You should escape the name with [escapeshellcmd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php).

Comment: Try to set time limit in PHP e-g  set_time_limit(0); 
http://php.net/set_time_limit

Comment: Yes, At submit its redirect and get response from python script. But after getting  output its again redirected.

Comment: So if you want to stay and show the result, don't redirect the user or wait a bit before redirecting? Btw, how are you redirecting the user? There's nothing in the above code that indicates any redirect.

Comment: I doesn't have any idea about this. Because I put whole code in question. Why browser redirect second time?How to stop this from redirect second time?

Comment: Anyone can help me? How will I show output on browser?

Comment: Now this php script hold the python output on sever, But for long python script execution it not show output.